# Loading large amounts of data into a List<MyObject> in .net

Tags: c#, wpf, mongodb, csv, large-data

I have a C# tool that parses a collection of csv files to construct a List. This collection can be small limited to 20 files or can be as large as 10000+ files. MyObject it self has about 20 properties most of them strings. Each file can create sometimes upto 4 items in the list and sometimes as many has 300.

After the parsing is done I first save the list to a csv file so I don't have to reparse the data again later. I then summarize the data by one pivot of the dataset and then there are multiple pivots to the dataset the user can choose. The data is presented in WPF and the user acts on the data and annotates the data with some additional information that then get's added to the MyObject. Finally the user can save all of this information to another csv file.

I ran into OOM when the files got large and have optimized some of my code. First I realized I was storing one parameter, i.e. the path to the csv file which was sometimes close to 255 characters. I changed it to only save the filename and things improved slightly. I then discovered a suggestion to compile to x64 that would give me 4 Gb of memory instead of 2 Gb.

Even with this obviously I hit OOM's when more and more files are added to this data set.

Some of the options I've considered are:

1. When parsing the files, save to the intermediate.csv file after each file parse and not keep the list in memory. This will work for me to avoid the step of seeing an OOM even before I get to save the intermediate.csv file. 
   Problem with this approach is I still have to load back the intermediate file into memory once the parsing is all done.
2. Some of the Properties on MyObject are similar for a collection of files. So I've considered refactoring the single object into multiple objects that will possibly reduce the number of items in the List object. Essentially refactoring to List, with MyTopLevelDetailsObject containing a List. The memory foot print should reduce theoretically. I can then output this to csv by doing some translation to make it appear like a single object.
3. Move the data to a db like MongoDB internally and load the data to summarize to the db logic.
4. Use DataTables instead.

Options 2 and 3 will be significant redesign with 3 also needing me to learn MongoDB. :)

I'm looking for some guidance and helpful tips of how Large data sets have been handled.

Regards,
LW

Comment: for such amount of data, database would be the best choice.

Comment: Essentially your application is an in-memory database which as you have seen has its limits.  Suggest you use a disk-based database storage system. i.e. pick your favorite RDBMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, after optimizations, the data can't fit in memory, almost by definition you need it to hit the disk.

Rather than reinvent the wheel and create a custom data format, it's generally best to use one of the well vetted solutions.  MongoDB is a good choice here, as are other database solutions.  I'm fond of SQLite, which despite the name, can handle large amounts of data and doesn't require a local server.

If you ever get to the point where fitting the data on a local disk is a problem, you might consider moving on to large data solutions like Hadoop.  That's a bigger topic, though.

Comment: I might just go with the SQLite option. Will save me lots of time instead of redoing the data structure. Thanks Anon.

Comment: @loganwol, +1 SQLite will probably provide you with all the functionality already implemented

Answer (score 2):

Options two and four can't probably help you because (as I see it) they won't reduce the total amount of information in memory.

Also consider an option to load data dynamically. I mean, the user probably can't see all data at one moment of time. So you may load  a part of .csv to the memory and show it to the user, then if the user made some annotations/edits you may save this chunk of data to a separate file.  If the user scrolls through data you load it on the fly. When the user wants to save final .csv you combine it from the original one and your little saved chunks.

This is often a practice when creating C# desktop application that access some large amounts of data. For example, I adopted loading data in chunks on the fly, when I needed to create a WinForms software to operate with a huge database (tables with more then 10m rows, they can't fit to mediocre office PCs memory).

And yes, too much work to do it with .csv manually. **It's easier to use some database** to handle saving/saving of edited parts/composition of final output.

Comment: The summary view that comes up first is such that it can be less than 10 lines in a DataGrid but the number of collections can be a 1000 with each collection representing about 30 csv files resulting in 3000 items in the list.

Comment: I don't see how it matters. My idea was "to implement your own simple not relational database with .csv files as it's backing data source". So information can be kept on disk and not in memory. What to do with it next and what objects to use is up to you.